# How union arrays with validate only one property

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

Joining of Arrays.

I'm in need of running a "Join Array" objects, but, I need duplicated objects to be removed, see:

Example

```
var objArray1 = [
    { Id: 1, Name: 'João', Order: 2 },
    { Id: 2, Name: 'Pedro', Order: 5 }
];

var objArray2 = [       
    { Id: 2, Name: 'Pedro', Order: 6 },
    { Id: 3, Name: 'Manoel', Order: 9 }
];
```

Actual code:

```
var result = _.union(objArray1,objArray2);  
=> [
    { Id: 1, Name: 'João', Order: 2 },
    { Id: 2, Name: 'Pedro', Order: 5 },
    { Id: 2, Name: 'Pedro', Order: 6 },
    { Id: 3, Name: 'Manoel', Order: 9 }
];
```

I need this result:

```
[
    { Id: 1, Name: 'João', Order: 2 },
    { Id: 2, Name: 'Pedro', Order: 5 },
    { Id: 3, Name: 'Manoel', Order: 9 } 
];
```

Basic I need join arrays with filter the one property, I need is possible with For but I would like a better solution

Comment: What about the order?

Comment: are both arrays orderd by id? and should the result remain the order?

Comment: have you tried using `_.uniq` on your `_.union` ?

Comment: Yes the two are ordered by ID

Comment: @DjonatasTenfen Added answer, kindly check if it works...

Comment: @Jaromanda X Yes, I tried using __.union_ see the code

Comment: @Praveen Kumar the result of the __.union_ is 

var result = _.union(objArray1,objArray2);  
=> [
    { Id: 1, Name: 'João', Order: 2 },
    { Id: 2, Name: 'Pedro', Order: 5 },
    { Id: 2, Name: 'Pedro', Order: 6 },
    { Id: 3, Name: 'Manoel', Order: 9 }
];

Comment: @DjonatasTenfen Okay... **Does my answer work for you?**

Comment: `_.uniq(array, [isSorted], [iteratee])` ... `iteratee` is an optional user function

Comment: @DjonatasTenfen - **did you read what I wrote?** ... did you try using `_.uniq` on the result of `_.union` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use underscore `unique` function as follows

```
var result = _.uniq(_.union(objArray1, objArray2), false, function(item){ return item.Id; });
```

not 100% sure if the `false` should be `true`

---

or, as seems to be a trend on SO - the sexy ES2015 version

```
var result = _.uniq(_.union(objArray1, objArray2), false, item => item.Id);
```

Comment: I don't think you should be passing `true` for the `sorted` parameter

Comment: It works by chance - probably wouldn't on other data sets.

Comment: Thanks, looks great.

Comment: You could even remove the last 2 parameters to `_.uniq` and replace with the string 'Id' e.g. `_.uniq(_.union(objArray1, objArray2), 'Id')`